# How to get intellisense for angular events in vs code

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I am following a Angular course on Udemy. The instructor is using vs code and when he uses events on button a whole list of events are shown to him like (click),(mousedown),(mouseenter) etc.

For example instructor writes:

<button (>Click me

He just opened the parenthesis inside button and he got a lot of suggestions of events.

In my vs code I don't get that type of suggestion. I would post screen shot of the video but for some reason the video screen turns black.

Answer (score 0):

The instructor is probably using "Angular Language Service" plugin you should install, as well as tslint, he should have talked about it in the course (I don't know for sure) if it's a 'get started' course, you might want to check.

Comment: I have already used those extensions. I am getting all kinds of suggestions except the events one

Answer (score 0):

Open Visual Studio Code

- Open Extensions on the left side of the IDE (ctrl + Shift + X  in windows)
- Search "Angular Language Service" and install

This will provide intellisense for Angular

[image]

Comment: I already have this extension enabled and i have restarted vs code too. but I still don't get suggestions for event. I do get suggestion for everything else.

Comment: check inside the tsconfig.app.json for the below code. Please add the below mentioned code to that and then it should work.

{
    "include": [
        "src/**/*.d.ts", 
        "src/**/*.ts"
      ]
}